# Craft Plugin Implementation: How to get handle of Field in getInputHtml() function

Tags: craft3

How to get handle of Field in getInputHtml() function.
This is my function:

```
 public function getInputHtml($value, ElementInterface $element = null): string
    { 
        $name='test';                  
        
        $id = \craft\helpers\Html::id($name);    
        
        $namespacedId = Craft::$app->view->namespaceInputId($id);                
        $data=Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate('craft-vimeo-handle/_fieldinput', [
            'name' => $name,
            'id' => $id,
            'namespacedId' => $namespacedId,
            'value' => $value,
        ]);           
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$this->handle` to access the field handle. Make sure you're using the trait [craft\base\FieldTrait](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-fieldtrait.html) which includes the [`handle` property](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-fieldtrait.html#handle).

Comment: Thanks, it works.